# Inverse filtering a blurred image - Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, filter

For an assignment, The image corrupted by atmospheric turbulence. I want to deblur an image using inverse image filtering. I have done some research and it seems I need the original image for this procedure but I only have the blurred image. How can I construct the degrading function that was used to blur this image? I am not allowed to use the original image. Thank you in advance.

This is the image:

[image: This is the original image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65857930/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: See this [library](https://github.com/PyLops/pylops_pydata2020) you might find it useful.

Comment: It seems useful but I am not allowed to use a third-party library.

Comment: you are supposed to use DeepLearning, or just simple image processing?

Comment: Just simple image processing.

Comment: one suggestion in my mind is to use edge detection, and combine the edges with the blurred image to partially de-blur it, it's hard task for simple image processing under these conditions.

Comment: The assignment question is this "Apply inverse filtering in order to restore the image ‘question_3.tif’ corrupted by atmospheric turbulence." So I cannot use other tecniques.

Comment: Do you have the filtering function (the kernel) that was used to blur this picture? Or do you have some idea of what the function for simulating "atmospheric turbulence" would be? I don't see how this would be a reasonable assignment without that.

Comment: Oh, there's someone else asking the exact same question. Apparently the Wiener Filter can estimate the unblur from a single picture.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use a third-party library." Can you clarify this statement? Are you saying that you have to write code from scratch? Deblurring is some advanced stuff.

Comment: OP repeatedly points out that using the original image is not allowed. Obviously. But I feel that more information than shown here is available on the blurring filter, model and parameters. Inverting that would still be a challenge, but much less than to try to determine that info from the blurred picture. I recommend to ask teacher/tutor about available info on the blur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deblurring an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743561/deblurring-an-image)

Comment: short answer is "you can’t, lost information cannot be recovered". Long answer is "you may make it *look* less blurry by doing things like reinforcing edges (using edge filters like eg sobel) or other more advanced techniques (some machine learning based algorithms are very efficient in that)

Comment: oh and if it was not really blurred by "atmostpheric turbulence", but just by a simple gaussian filter in frequency domain, you may just apply the inverse of that transform in fourier domain